# not able to download a file from my server in android default browser when using https

Tags: android, django, android-browser

I am trying to download my file(txt, apk, pdf) fom my django server in android default browser with secure https connection

the code of my server is

```
@csrf_exempt
def user_location(request):
print '----------------INSIDE user_location------------'
from prototype.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
download_name = "abc.txt"
import os, tempfile, zipfile
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
from django.conf import settings
import mimetypes
filename = MEDIA_ROOT + "/downloads/" + download_name    
print filename, '<- ------------------------------DOWNLOAD FILE NAME'
wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filename, 'rb'))
content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
response = HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type=content_type)
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="abc_v01.txt"'
print '----------------INSIDE user_location END------------'
return response
```

If i am using http in place of https than everything is fine but I have to use https rather than http is it possible to do so or is this a bug in android browser
any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: android requires real certificates to work with https

Comment: @njzk2 can you please elaborate i mean to make it work what i have to do. what exactly u mean by real certificate

Comment: the **S** in https means secure. security is achieved by use of certificates. certificates need to be installed (or to have one of their root certificate installed) for android to recognize it.

Comment: Just now I saw that the same site works in a Microsoft phone with https. Also, with just http, it works (Tried in local development server). So it has something to do with android & https. I'm not very sure about installing a certificate? is it something that should work like the way, it works on browsers? i.e., it checks the certificate and proceeds if it's fine? I'm not very sure what a user might think about installing something for just downloading a file from some site.

Comment: the easiest way is to use a certificate issued by verisign or thawte.